# Is identifying the best in randomly chosen $n$ elements, equivalent to identifying one from the best half of randomly chosen $2n$ elements?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, approximation-algorithms, algorithmic-randomness

Suppose we are given a set $U$, and a black-box objective function $f: U \mapsto [0, 1]$. The job is to maximise $f(\cdot)$. Now, for a given $\delta \in (0,1)$, consider the following randomised algorithms:

$\mathbf{\text{Algo_1}}$:
Uniformly at random choose a subset $S_n \subset U$ consisting of $n$ points, and return $\max_{i \in S_n} f(i)$, with probability at least $1-\delta$.

$\mathbf{\text{Algo_2}}$:
Uniformly at random choose a subset $S_{2n} \subset U$ consisting of $2n$ points, and return a point that is better than at least $n$ points in $S_{2n}$ with probability at least $1-\delta$. Therefore, if $i_0$ is the output, for *any* $n$-sized subset $T_n \subset S_{2n}$, it satisfies: $\forall j \in T_n, f(i_0) \geq f(j)$ with probability at least $1-\delta$.

**Question:**
If $e_1 \in U, e_2  \in U$ are the solutions obtained by ${\text{Algo_1}}$, and ${\text{Algo_2}}$ respectively, can we claim $\mathbb{E}[f(e_1)] = \mathbb{E}[f(e_2)]$? If not, can we find an $\epsilon$, such that $|\mathbb{E}[f(e_1)] = \mathbb{E}[f(e_2)]| <= \epsilon$ with some probabilistic guarantee?

**Note**: Irrespective of correctness of the output both the algorithms stops within a finite number of steps with absolute certainty.

Comment: What happens in each algorithm on the event of probability $\delta$ where it fails?

Comment: @YuvalPeres in case of error: for Algo_1, the output element is not the best in $S_n$, and for Algo_2 the output element does not belong to the best half of $S_{2n}$. However, irrespective of the correctness of the output, both the algorithms stop within a finite number of steps with absolute certainty.

Comment: Is it clear what happens if $\delta=0$, so one algorithm always gives the best element in a random set of size $n$, while the other always gives an element in the top half of a set of size $2n$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson sorry, $\delta = 0$ is not a valid input. As both of them are randomised algo (estimate f(.) from the samples) therefore, zero error is not a practical assumption.

Comment: An algorithm can certainly calculate $f(i)$ for all $i$ in a finite set, and then pick out the largest result with zero error, no? That's the algorithm I'm asking about.